# "mkdir vault: permission denied" when using docker-vault with kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I successfully deployed with kubernetes a custom container based on the official docker-vault image, but when using the `vault init` command I get the following error:

```
* failed to initialize barrier: failed to persist keyring: mkdir vault: permission denied
```

My Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM vault:0.8.3

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN chmod +x ./configure_vault.sh
CMD ["server", "-config=vault.conf"]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to execute a shell script after the container is started in order to configure the vault. I have a configuration script that starts like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export VAULT_ADDR="http://127.0.0.1:8200"
vault init -key-shares=1 -key-threshold=1 > vault_credentials
...
// configure some default roles and policies
```

To execute it, I configured my kubernetes yaml deployment file as follows:

```
...
spec:
      containers:
      - image: // my image
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: vault
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8200
            name: vaultport
            protocol: TCP
        # Enable mlock for the vault executable to stop
        # memory being swapped to disk so that secrets
        # don’t get written to disk.
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - IPC_LOCK
        volumeMounts:
        - name: vault-volume
          mountPath: /vault/file
        lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command: ["/bin/sh", "./configure_vault.sh"]
      volumes:
        - name: vault-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: vault
```

I can see that the vault user has the correct rights over the /vault folder so I can't seem to understand why a directory creation would fail. I tried giving root privileges to the vault user or executing the script manually by using `kubernetes exec` to get a shell to the container but none of it worked.

I'm not sure this is the correct way to proceed so any advice is welcome!

Comment: Is the user with which you're running the script in the owners group of the folder it's trying to `mkdir` in?

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake..! The docker-vault image creates a vault user which is the owner of the whole /vault folder. I thought this was the folder it was trying to `mkdir` into but it's actually trying to create it in my Docker /app workdir. I gave the vault user the rights to the /app folder and it worked... Thanks @mickburkejnr !

Comment: Not a stupid mistake at all, just one of those things. Nearly every project I work on/start I always make this mistake because I forget about the user groups!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check your PV. If you are using hostpath then you will have to navigate to the host on which the pod is being scheduled and grant write permissions on the directory which is specified in the PV.
You should be good after that.